# Deathfire Touch vs. Thunderlord's Decree on Jhin

Tags: league-of-legends

How do Deathfire Touch and Thunderlord's Decree compare on Jhin? What are the pros and cons of both?

Answer (score 6):

Deathfire Touch scales off AD (60% on single target abilities, 30% on AOE abilities, 15% on DOT abilities).
The reason this is desirable on Jhin is his passive, Whisper gives him AD based on level AND based on his crit chance. As you're probably aware, Jhin can end up with some ridiculous "OmgWhatIsHappening" amounts of AD.
In comparison, Thunderlord's Decree only scales on a flat 30% of Bonus AD and 10% of Bonus AP.

Since Jhin's W and R are treated as single target spells, and his Q is 'AOE', you get better scaling power with Deathfire Touch than Thunderlords's.

**Single Target**

It's also very easy for Jhin to keep the burn going. Chances are you'll land the Q and W burns (followed by each other in whichever order), and if the target escapes, your ult will also apply it.

Likewise, Thunderlords is most likely going to proc - but only once, and the scaling on AD as mentioned is lower, but if the fight is going to be short (no time for burn damage), the thunderlord damage likely more worth it.

Also, if you're sitting in a bush waiting for a quick 1v1 prey, you might want the instant burst damage that thunderlord brings.
But if you're running from that pesky Garen, chances are the burn from DFT will be doing more than half your damage!

**Fighting**

Thunderlords will only proc once (maybe twice in teamfights), whereas your Q, and your E, is definitely going to be hitting targets, and the burn damage should far outscale the Thunderlord.

DFT seems to be the clear winner, but that's not really the case either.
As mentioned, DFT gets really strong when you get your items (especially crit items, which are expensive), but until you get these items, you likely won't notice it much.
This is where Thunderlord's shines; You'll notice it far earlier in the game.

That should cover pros and cons pretty well; But which is then best?
That question can be answered with another question;

**Do you need a boost in lane, or do you need a boost in teamfights?**

If you wanna try dominating lane harder, you should go with Thunderlord's.
If you plan on being laid back and going later into the game (ex. if your teamcomp favors it), DFT should be the choice.

This 'trend' can also be spotted if you check websites that show recent games from players (I won't mention names here) - Different players have different choices, but it is indeed between these two

Answer (score 0):

As someone who mostly plays lategame champs i would go deathfire.

thunderlords : more damage early game .

deathfire : much more damage (than thunderlords) lategame .

You can see their scaling . thunderlords' damage is ignorable in lategame and teamfights . 
But many times it has happened that after my death Deathfire killed someone (below 15% hp)